# The behavior of svg images in the flex box

Tags: html, css, svg, flexbox

I am currently studying css flexbox and I have a few questions about using svg images inside flex box.
If a  [svg img is inside in the body of a html document](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GGDRWWQCD2KZ), the width of the svg image is the same as the width of the body.When I put `display:flex` to the body tag, the [svg image in centered vertically and the size is reduced](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GGDS7XGFWQ9Y), it doesn't behave the same as a [jpg image which would expand it whole height to match the body's height](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GGDSBKLONWFR). This is the first point which confuses me.

The second point is that when i put [the svg inside a div, the svg will disappear.](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GGDSHQACMVBF). I have read a [stackoverflow post about this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46922999/inline-svg-disappears-with-flexbox) and it stated that it is because the svg didn't have an internal width/height set. But why the svg image didn't disappear in the case without the div? It is the same image meaning that the internal width/height are not set too. [And If I put one more svg inside the div, the svg images magically appears with a tiny width and height.](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GGDSKNPR7QSI)The sag images are aligned vertical instead of horizontally too. Why are they reappear when more then one svg is put inside the div?

I am sorry for my poor english as english is not my mother language.

Comment: First, try adding width/height attributes to your <img> tags. Your problems are not related to SVG. About flex. Every element inside flex behaves as column or row. If you want to take 100% width add `width: 100%` or `flex-basis: 100%`.

Answer (score 2):

For your first point, you need to add:

```
align-items:flex-start; // add it to the body.
```

if you need to add a width for div:

```
width:100%;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style>
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  display:flex;
  background: #060AB2;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
}

div{
    border:3px solid black;
    background:green; 
    width:100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <img class="back-face" src="https://marina-ferreira.github.io/memory-game/img/js-badge.svg" alt="JS Badge" />
   <img class="back-face" src="https://marina-ferreira.github.io/memory-game/img/js-badge.svg" alt="JS Badge" />
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```